# fork() vs. CreateProcess(). System call vs. API?

Tags: api, winapi, fork, posix, system-calls

Assuming that APIs are generally similar(and in some cases same) to the System Calls they invoke....

Does the *fork()* we invoke in our user application, a 'API in POSIX' which invokes the actual system call **'fork()'**? Or do we directly invoke ***fork()*** system call?

And how does it compares to *CreateProcess()* in Win32 API.

Is ***CreateProcess()*** a system call which invokes another system call **NTCreateProcess()** system call OR Is *CreateProcess()* a function in the Win32 API which invokes **NTCreateProcess()** system call?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: is your question about what functions call what other functions, or simply about what names we give to the functions that call other functions?

Comment: the former. Broadly to say I'm confused about 'what is a system call and what is an API'?

Comment: API stands for "Application Program Interface". It's basically a set of types, functions, etc., for use by programs. "System call" doesn't have a really tight definition though--it's pretty much just "some function I can call that's provided by the system."

Comment: Why do you care? What's the motivation for the Q?

Comment: Differentiating between API & system calls? It's all just theory ofcourse!

Comment: CreateProcess is an API call. Internally it is implemented, eventually, with a system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak for Linux and UNIX variants, but I imagine Windows is similar.

> Does the fork() we invoke in our user application, a 'API in POSIX'
>   which invokes the actual system call 'fork()'? Or do we directly
>   invoke fork() system call?

In Linux, `fork(2)` is a syscall, but recent Linux versions don't use it in most cases. When you call `fork(2)` from a C user program, you're calling the glibc wrapper, not the real syscall - as of the latest version, the glibc wrapper invokes `clone(2)` and passes it the necessary flags to indicate the attributes of the new process. `clone(2)` is the real syscall (see `man 2 clone`).

However, even if you call `clone(2)` directly in a C program, you will be calling the glibc wrapper function. Most raw syscalls have an equivalent wrapper function in glibc because raw syscall invocation is architecture dependent.

Some manpages include the prototype for both, the wrapper and the raw syscall. For example, the manpage for `clone(2)` shows both variants:

```
SYNOPSIS
/* Prototype for the glibc wrapper function */

#include <sched.h>

int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack,
          int flags, void *arg, ...
          /* pid_t *ptid, struct user_desc *tls, pid_t *ctid */ );

/* Prototype for the raw system call */

long clone(unsigned long flags, void *child_stack,
            void *ptid, void *ctid,
            struct pt_regs *regs);
```

You can usually learn a lot from the manpages. `man 2 fork` mentions what I said above in the notes section:

> NOTES
>
> Under  Linux,  fork()  is  implemented  using copy-on-write
>   pages, so the only penalty that it incurs is the time and memory
>   required to duplicate the parent's page tables, and to create a unique
>   task structure for the child.
>
> Since version 2.3.3, rather than invoking the kernel's fork() system
>   call, the glibc fork() wrapper that is provided as part of the NPTL
>   threading  implementation invokes clone(2) with flags that provide the
>   same effect as the traditional system call.  (A call to fork() is
>                                                                equivalent to a call to clone(2) specifying flags as just SIGCHLD.)  The glibc wrapper invokes any fork handlers that
>   have  been  established using pthread_atfork(3).

(If you're wondering, NPTL stands for [Native POSIX Threads Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library))

TL;DR When you're programming, you never really invoke syscalls directly. You invoke the glibc wrappers that handle the nitty gritty details of raw syscall invocation.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffy Coffin pointed, API stands for Application Program Interface, and is a document that describes a set of functions, related types and other language interfaces and features for use by applications. An API can be pretty much anything. For example Stack Exchange has a [web API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) that can be used by anything capable of making HTTP requests over the Internet.

Also, as Jerry Coffin said the term "system call" isn't very well defined. It just means an API function that implements an operating service. You could argue that neither CreateProcess nor NTCreateProcess are system calls. Both are C wrappers around the true system call, which is bit code written in assembly. On the other hand, I'd argue they're both system calls. They both offer access to the operating system's facility for creating new processes with no significant extra added functionality. Either way, it doesn't really matter.